# How to make cookie to safe

Tags: php, cookies

My question it is how i make safe cookie? In my site users login and engine create cookie "userid" and value it is username. But Problem it is all user can make same cookie and get what account he want. And the reason why i use cookie it is the time. I want to create cookie what is active in 15 minutes and if user use in login "remember me" cookie is active 1 mounth.

There is the code what i paste in JavaScript Console and create same cookie what engine create:

```
document.cookie="userid=what username i want to use";
```

So how i solve this problem? What is safest and best way to do this cookie / session?

Thanks for help!

Comment: what "engine" is inferred in your question?

Comment: I code own cms, but is not ready

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User login is usually handled with PHP sessions because its server sided an no user can change the data on the server. Your question really is how to identify a user that came back to the website.

By default, if you start a session with PHP a cookie is generated called PHP_SID with a unique hash which is practically un-guessable by manually changing it. The chance of duplication is so low that its unique per user.

If you wish to improve on that security you can check the users browser-user-agent to see if it matches the previous visit to your website.

Now that you have a specific user ID your session data will automatically load up and you have your user data available in PHP to be printed out on your website.

Comment: Yeah, i know how to use $_SESSION, but if i use $_SESSION i can't make active time and there is the problem.

Comment: Sure you can, create a cookie "rememberme" with a time and also store that data in the session. If the user with that ID comes back and you verify if that has expired (with the session and cookie , must all be the same) destroy it and restart it otherwise continue as the user has never left your site.

Comment: Thanks! I think i can make remember cookie and storage db the ip address, token key and expire time. If ip address and token its not true auth fail..

Comment: An IP address is these days not so smart to do, cause people usually grab their phone and their IP addresses can change.